# Toggle the visibility of a Text Field on a click of a button - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Text Field and a button in my Xamarin Forms application. If the current visibility of the button is true, and if the user clicks on the button, the visibility needs to change to false, and vice-versa.

To add further complexity, the visibility of the text field also change to false if the user clicks on any other part of the  page.

This is XAML part of the text field

```
<controls:CustomEntry 
         x:Name="FirstNameEntry"
         Text= "{Binding FirstName}"
         IsVisible="{Binding EntryVisible}">
         <controls:CustomEntry.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger TargetType="controls:CustomEntry"
                  Binding="{Binding EntryVisible}" Value="true">
                  <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <triggers:EntryFocusTrigger/>
                  </Trigger.EnterActions>
              </DataTrigger>
              <Trigger TargetType="controls:CustomEntry"
                   Property="IsFocused" Value="false">
                   <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="false" />
               </Trigger>
           </controls:CustomEntry.Triggers>
  </controls:CustomEntry>
```

Note : The data trigger that I have in my XAML is to get the focus to the Entry, when the user clicks on button so that the Keyboard is also visible.

This is my button code

```
 <Button 
      Text="Key in Name" 
      Command="{Binding ToggleEntryCommand}"
      HeightRequest="50"/>
```

Command in ViewModel

```
 public Command ToggleEntryCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                EntryVisible = !EntryVisible;
            });
        }
    }
```

Trigger Code

```
public class EntryFocusTrigger : TriggerAction<CustomEntry>
{
    protected override void Invoke(CustomEntry entry)
    {
        entry.Focus();
    }

}
```

**Current Issue**

If the user toggles on the button, the visibility of the text fields works as expected.

***But if the user clicks else where on the page, the Text field would disappear, but the user would now need to click twice on the button to turn the visibility back on.***

I would appreciate your help to fix this. I have also tried, to make the binding mode = two way for the EntryVisible property. But really does not fix the issue.

I would also like to know if there is a more elegant way to write the same without having to use the code-behind file.

Comment: can you share the ```EntryFocusTrigger``` here?

Comment: @Motumbo : I have now. Please check the edited code

Comment: ```Binding="{Binding EntryVisible}" Value="true">``` try to set Value to false and see what happens

Comment: and behind code (ugly solution)
```protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
             myViewModel.IsEntryVisible = FirstNameEntry.IsVisible;
        }```

Answer (score 0):

May be, use binding for property EntryVisible to below

```
 <Trigger TargetType="controls:CustomEntry"
               Property="IsFocused" Value="false">
               <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="false" />
           </Trigger>
```